# Zend framework 2 - standalone forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

Is it possible to use the ZF2 forms a as standalone component? This was possible with ZF1, but I can't figure it out with ZF2.

I can create a form and a validator, but can't figure out how to render the form:

```
$form = new AddressBookForm('address_book'); \\ extends Zend\Form\Form

if ($this->input->isPost()) {
    $validator = new AddressBookValidator(); \\ implements Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface
    $form->setInputFilter($validator->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($this->input->getPost());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        echo 'valid'; exit;
    }
}

// Render form somehow here???
```

I tried creating a view, but couldn't figure out how to give it the view helpers. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to render a ZF2 form without the full MVC? :)

Comment: No, I gave up and used ZF1 instead.

Answer (score 7):

I have a basic solution, that seems to do the job

```
$zfView = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$plugins = $zfView->getHelperPluginManager();
$config  = new Zend\Form\View\HelperConfig;
$config->configureServiceManager($plugins);
```

and then render the form

```
echo $zfView->form()->openTag($form);
echo $zfView->formRow($form->get('name'));
echo $zfView->formSubmit( $form->get('submit'));
echo $zfView->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 5):

Checkout this blog.

[Form Render in View file](http://www.kdecom.com/display-form-using-one-line-in-view-file-zend-framework-2/)

you can do simply by zend framework form view helper.

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$this->form()->render($form);
```

Comment: I guess last line should be `echo $this->form()->render($form);`

Answer (score 3):

@CodeMonkey's method is a good one but the code is incomplete. I cobbled together a working example from his and other answers I found with partial code.

```
<?php
    /*
     * @author Carl McDade
     * 
     * @since 2012-06-11
     * @version 0.2
     *
     */

namespace zftest;

$path = DOCROOT .'/_frameworks/zf/ZendFramework-2.2.2/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
require_once($path . '/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php');

use Zend\Loader;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;


use Zend\Captcha;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\FormInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper;

use \Common;

class zftest{


function __construct()
{

    spl_autoload_register(array($this, '_zftest_autoload'));
}

 function _zftest_autoload($class)
 {
     //
     $loader = new \Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
     $loader->registerNamespaces(array('Zend'));

     // finally send namespaces and prefixes to the autoloader SPL
     $loader->register();
     return;
 }

function zftest()
{



    $uri = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
    $address = urlencode('berlin');
    $sensor = 'false';

    $request = new Request();
    $request->setUri($uri);
    $request->setMethod('GET');

    $client = new Client($uri);
    $client->setRequest($request);
    $client->setParameterGet(array('sensor'=>$sensor,'address'=>$address));
    $response = $client->dispatch($request);        
    if ($response->isSuccess()) {
        print 'Your Request for:<pre>' . print_r($address, 1) . '</pre>';
        print '<pre>' . print_r($response->getBody(), 1) . '</pre>';

    }
}

function zfform()
{



    // Zend Framework 2 form example

    $name = new Element('name');
    $name->setLabel('Your name');
    $name->setAttributes(array(
        'type'  => 'text'
    ));

    $email = new Element\Email('email');
    $email->setLabel('Your email address');

    $subject = new Element('subject');
    $subject->setLabel('Subject');
    $subject->setAttributes(array(
        'type'  => 'text'
    ));

    $message = new Element\Textarea('message');
    $message->setLabel('Message');

    $captcha = new Element\Captcha('captcha');
    $captcha->setCaptcha(new Captcha\Dumb());
    $captcha->setLabel('Please verify you are human');

    $csrf = new Element\Csrf('security');

    $send = new Element('send');
    $send->setValue('Submit');
    $send->setAttributes(array(
        'type'  => 'submit'
    ));


    $form = new Form('contact');
    $form->add($name);
    $form->add($email);
    $form->add($subject);
    $form->add($message);
    $form->add($captcha);
    $form->add($csrf);
    $form->add($send);

    $nameInput = new Input('name');
    // configure input... and all others
    $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
    // attach all inputs

    $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

    $zfView = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
    $plugins = $zfView->getHelperPluginManager();
    $config  = new \Zend\Form\View\HelperConfig;
    $config->configureServiceManager($plugins);

    $output = $zfView->form()->openTag($form) . "\n";
    $output .= $zfView->formRow($form->get('name')) . "<br />\n";
    $output .= $zfView->formRow($form->get('captcha')) . "<br />\n";
    $output .= $zfView->formSubmit( $form->get('send')) . "<br />\n";
    $output .= $zfView->form()->closeTag() . "\n";

    echo $output;

}
}
?>
```

Comment: This and @CodeMonkey's code put me in the right path. Thanks!

Comment: You  can see a working demo at http://co2kit.net/cck/development/?zftest/zfform.  I have included two examples in my CCK framework project. I*ll also put them in the package on Github  so people can download and play with a working example locally

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Zend\Form\View\Helper` view helpers to render the form inside a view.
Example: (view context)

```
My Form: 
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form); ?>
<?php echo $this->formCollection($this->form); ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($this->form); ?>
```

**Note** that `$this->form` is the `$form` variable assigned to the view. Also, view helpers are always available in views as far as they are registered as `invokables` (this is always true for built-in helpers).

This would render all elements inside a `<form ...> ... </form>` tag.
Check the other view helpers for further information.

Also, see the example docs: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html
There's a lot more you can do with this.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm not using the MVC. How do I create this view?

Answer (score 0):

None of the simpler answers helped me since I did not have Service Manager set up nor the View Helper methods.

But in a hurry this worked for me:

```
    $checkbox = new Element\Checkbox('checkbox');
    $checkbox->setLabel('Label');

    $checkbox->setCheckedValue("good");
    $checkbox->setUncheckedValue("bad");

    $form = new FormCheckbox();
    echo $form->render($checkbox);
```